# Factor variable registering as numeric level [R]

Tags: r

I have a factor variable Category (e.g., Category A, B, C), and I am trying to fill any blank values in the column with NA. However, when I run this command, the Category variable is replaced with integer values representing the levels of the factor. How do I go about retaining the actual factor characters?

```
full$CATEGORY <- ifelse(full$CATEGORY == "", NA, full$CATEGORY)
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer.  Avoid `ifelse` for this use case.  If you defined your data something like this

```
> full=data.frame(CATEGORY=factor(c('a','b','','d','a','')))
```

Then you can accomplish what you want with an assignment statement. **This will avoid having to spend time converting and then converting back.**

```
> full$CATEGORY[full$CATEGORY=='']=NA
> full
  CATEGORY
1        a
2        b
3     <NA>
4        d
5        a
6     <NA>
>
```

Comment: This works, +1, but for completeness, an alternative way of doing the same is `is.na(full$CATEGORY) <- full$CATEGORY == ""`. According to the `?NA` docs: "Function `is.na<-` may provide a safer way to set missingness. It behaves differently for factors, for example." but I'm yet to find a case where this made any difference.